# Suppose $a_n \to a$ and $a_n \geq b$ for all $n.$ Show that $a \geq b$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> **Problem:** Suppose $a_n \to a$ and $a_n \geq b$ for all $n$. Show that $a \geq b$.
>
> **My proof:**
> Assume that $b > a$ and let $\epsilon = b - a$. By definition if $\{a_n\}$ converges then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$. By expanding the absolute value, I see that $a_n - a < b- a$. By adding $a$ to both sides, we get that $a_n < b$ a contradiction.

Is my proof correct? And is there any way to tackle a problem like this without constructing an $\epsilon$?

Comment: Your proof is correct. I don't see how you would want a "shorter" proof or a proof without $\varepsilon$'s ; it's really not that much complicated. Proofs that will not involve it will assume theorems that actually do the $\varepsilon$ work in their proofs essentially.

Comment: Let $c_n:=a_n-b$, $c_n\geq0$ for all $n$, and $\lim c_n=a-b\geq 0$, hence $a\geq b$

Comment: Do you have the Monotonicity Theorem to work with? It says $a_n\ge b_n$ for all $n$ implies $\lim a_n \ge \lim b_n$. That would make quick work of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but you’ve not handled the absolute value carefully enough, and the wording could be considerably improved. For instance, you should say where $N$ comes from. Here’s a better version that sticks reasonably closely to what you wrote.

> Assume that $b>a$, and let $\epsilon=b-a>0$. Since $a_n\to a$, there must be some positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$. In particular, $|a_N-a|<b-a$. There are now two possibilities. If $a_N\ge a$, then $|a_N-a|=a_N-a$, and we can add $a$ to both sides to get $a_N<b$, a contradiction. And if $a_N<a$, then $a_N<a<b$, with the same contradiction. Thus, it’s impossible that $b>a$, and hence $a\ge b$.